# Referencing @Section Scripts within Div

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, knockout.js

Having issues calling `@section scripts{...}` within a `div`. Currently, it states `Uncaught Error: Unknown component 'product-chooser`.

> **Question:** How can I call my partial from within a div so that it puts the content near the top of the page?

**Section of code giving me issues:**

```
@section scripts{
    @Html.Partial("ProductChooserScript", Model)
}
```

**View: *ProductSelector***

```
<div id="productForm">
    @using(Html.BeginForm())
    {
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="input-group" data-bind="visible: false, component: { name: 'product-chooser' , params: { value: TargetedProducts, available: AvailableProducts, selected: SelectedProducts }}"></div>
            @* Failing Here *@
            <div>
                @section scripts{
                @Html.Partial("ProductChooserScript", Model)
            }
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function ProductSelectionViewModel(data){
        var self = this;

        // additional javascript/knockout logic here...
    }

    $(function (){
        window.viewModel = new ProductSelectionViewModel(@Html.Json(Model));

        ko.applyBindings(window.viewModel, $("#productForm")[0])
    })
</script>
```

**Additional Notes:**

If I remove the `div` surrounding `@section scripts{...}` and put it at the bottom of the page, it renders the partial, but the partial gets rendered at the bottom of the page (not the desired results), I'd like it to get rendered near the top.

> **Please note that I did research... The other sources did not resolve this issue.**

- [How can i load Partial view inside the view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7295835/how-can-i-load-partial-view-inside-the-view)
- [How to render partial view in some specific div without using ajax in asp.net mvc 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10778055/how-to-render-partial-view-in-some-specific-div-without-using-ajax-in-asp-net-mv)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further research, I was able to resolve my issue. The error was with my `knockout`... I moved my `@section scripts{...}` to the bottom of my view and then created a `div` with an `id` of `productChooser`.

Previously, my `ko.components.register...` was appending the `body`, which was getting rendered at the bottom of the page. After changing the append to my `productChooser`, it rendered as expected.

**My View: *ProductSelector***

```
<div id="productForm">
    @using(Html.BeginForm())
    {
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="input-group" data-bind="visible: false, component: { name: 'product-chooser' , params: { value: TargetedProducts, available: AvailableProducts, selected: SelectedProducts }}"></div>
            <div id="productChooser"></div>    
        </div>
    }
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function ProductSelectionViewModel(data){
        var self = this;

        // additional javascript/knockout logic here...
    }

    $(function (){
        window.viewModel = new ProductSelectionViewModel(@Html.Json(Model));

        ko.applyBindings(window.viewModel, $("#productForm")[0])
    })
</script>
@section scripts{
    @Html.Partial("ProductChooserScript", Model)
}
```

**ProductChooserScript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function (){
     ko.components.register('product-chooser', {
    viewModel: {
        createViewModel: function (params) {
            var chooserModel = new ViewModel(params);
            var modalHtml = $('#product-chooser-template').html();
            $('#productChooser').append(modalHtml);
            var el = $('#MyModal')[0];
            ko.applyBindings(chooserModel, el);
            initializeControl(chooserModel);
            return chooserModel;
        }
    },
    template: $('#product-chooser-preview-template').html()
});
})();
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

First, the location in the view code where you define a section has no bearing on anything. In other words, just because you define it within that div doesn't mean the content of the section will end up there. The section is rendered wherever the layout calls `RenderSection`.

Second, you can only define sections in layouts or views that utilize layouts. Partial views cannot define sections, because partial views don't reference a layout.